# POST API command with space in strings erroring out in Powershell via HTTPie

Tags: api, powershell, powershell-4.0, httpie

I'm getting an error when I have a `POST` command with spaces in the string, such as `"I like cars"`.

[image: Powershell Error]

The `"follow-ups"` is an API identifier.

I've tried adding a `'` (single quote) before/after the string, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Why aren't you using `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebRequest`?  With such complex quoting requirements, you might be best off using the stop-parser operator (`--%`)

Comment: post the command please. please avoid pictures :)

Comment: @ArcSet here's the command: http POST https://url.com fields:='{\"follow-ups\":\"I like cars\"}' user=randomnumbers Token:randomnumbers

Comment: I'm not familiar with invoke-restmethod :/ anyone else have any suggestions?

Comment: @380625 any chance you can help out with this?!